# How to remove the default set logo from the title page and the ToC's page

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

How to remove a logo from the title page and from the ToC's page, please?

Using this code :

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\author{The Author}
\title{Work Culture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.5cm]{mylogo}}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
\framesubtitle{Test subtitle}
test text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: in your example is no logo on the title page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line makes the logo appear on every page, except in the first page

```
 \logo{\includegraphics[height=0.5cm]{mylogo}}
```

By removing the line above, the image will no longer appear.

If you want to display the logo in all pages except the title page and the ToC, define these frames before the \logo command.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\author{The Author}
\title{Work Culture}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\end{frame}

\logo{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{mylogo}}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
\framesubtitle{Test subtitle}
 test text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```